# Los ficheros no heredan permisos de la carpeta superior usando PHP y Apache

Tags: php, linux, apache

He creado un script en PHP que me copia una serie de ficheros de imagen a una carpeta compartida en otro servidor.

La carpeta compartida tiene asignados los permisos `rwx` a todos los usuarios/grupos quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
drwxrwxrwx  59 www-data  www-data  2006 19 ago 10:15 Z_LISTADO
```

El script, lógicamente, se ejecuta desde el servidor web con su usuario por defecto `www-data`.

El problema que tengo es que al copiar las imágenes éstas no heredan los permisos del directorio superior `Z_LISTADO`, si no que se les asignan los siguientes permisos:

```
drwxrwxrwx  6 www-data  www-data       204 19 ago 10:27 .
drw-r--r--+ 8 www-data  www-data       272 16 ago 16:05 ..
-rw-------  1 www-data  www-data   9389509 19 ago 10:27 03940.jpg
-rw-------  1 www-data  www-data   4629716 19 ago 10:27 04758.jpg
-rw-------  1 www-data  www-data  11524286 19 ago 10:27 14306.jpg
-rw-------  1 www-data  www-data   3358720 19 ago 10:27 23530.jpg
```

Posteriormente no puedo utilizarlos con otro usuario que no sea `www-data`.

¿Alguien ha tenido un problema similar? No sé si puedo crear un `umask` a nivel de usuario de Apache o hay algún detalle que se me pasa.

Comment: ¿Probaste algo de lo que te propuse en la última edición?

Comment: Tu solución parece lógica pero mi sistema no es un linux convencional es un macos Server. El comando setfacl no existe. Apple da una alternativa a nivel de ficheros que 'suplanta' el típico setfacl en este hilo hay mas info: https://support.apple.com/es-es/HT201684 Al tener que aplicarlo en un servidor virtual primero tengo que hacer un backup y realizar el testing en fin de semana.

Comment: Creo que ese dato era muy importante hacerlo puesto en la pregunta. No sé cómo modificar los ACLs en MacOS, pero tengo un compañero que podría ayudarme con ese tema. Con la solución del `umask` (si no te importa que el permiso de ejecución no lo tenga) o `chmod` (si es importante), y los permisos de paso (dar `a+x` a los directorio padres de `Z_LISTADO`) debería solucionarse el problema.

Comment: Creo que la forma de agregar herencia en el directorio ([viendo esto](https://ss64.com/osx/chmod.html)) podría ser algo como agregar varias ACLs como `chmod +a "others allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit" /ruta_a/Z_LISTADO`. No tengo un Mac a mano para probar, pero `directory_inherit` y `file_inherit` deberían hacer el trabajo o, al menos, darte una pista de qué permisos deben agregarse mediante este método.

Comment: Esa es la solución de la que hablaban en el otro hiloque te pasé. Tus explicaciones y comentarios me aydaron mucho. Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

En Linux no existe herencia de permisos sin usar ACLs (ver notas al final), sólo de dueños mediante el [bit pegajoso `t` (`sticky`)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit), y su funcionamiento no es cambiar los dueños de los archivos de manera directa, si no superponer los dueños del directorio a los del archivo.

Para hacer lo que deseas debes hacer uso de [`umask()`](https://php.net/umask) en tu script de PHP que realiza la escritura de archivos para indicarle a PHP que cree los archivos con los permisos deseados:

```
umask(0);
```

En este caso 0 significa todos los permisos, que se traduce en `rw-rw-rw-` porque a la hora de crear archivos no se otorga el bit de ejecución si no es a través de [`chmod()`](https://php.net/chmod).

**Nota en entornos multihilo:**

> Evite usar esta función en servidores web multihilo. Es mejor cambiar los permisos de fichero con `chmod()` después de crear el fichero. Usar `umask()` puede llevar a comportamientos inesperados en los scripts que se ejecutan concurrentemente y en el servidor web mismo, ya que pueden usar la misma máscara de usuario.

El módulo de PHP para Apache (`mod_php`) no se ejecuta en multihilo, si no por hijo, por lo que no te afecta esta nota, pero debería tener en cuenta que es otra forma de cambiar los permisos a los archivos cuando ya han sido creados.

**Nota adicional en los permisos de directorios:**

Acabo de ver que tienes estos permisos en el directorio padre:

```
drw-r--r--+ 8 www-data  www-data       272 16 ago 16:05 ..
```

Si el directorio padre no tiene los permisos `x` ningún usuario del grupo o ajeno al grupo podrá pasar a través de él. El permiso `r` permite hacer un listado de directorio, pero sin el `x` no podrá atravesar por él para acceder a un subdirectorio.

**Solución haciendo uso de ACLs:**

Viendo que el directorio padre tiene ACLs he pensado que haciendo uso ACLs sí que es posible configurar herencia de permisos modificando los permisos por defecto (*default* ) con `--default`/`-d`:

```
setfacl --default --modify u::rwx,g::rwx,o::rwx <directorio>
```

Para ver los permisos del directorio:

```
$ getfacl <directorio>
# file: <directorio>
# owner: usuario
# group: grupo
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::rwx
```

Los permisos por defecto se heredan, a diferencia de los permisos normales. En el ejemplo se puede ver que los permisos del directorio no han cambiado, pero al crearse nuevos elementos tendrán los permisos de `default:*`.

Ahora ocurriría igual que antes, al crear un archivo se crearía con los permisos `rw-rw-rw-` y un directorio con `drwxrwxrwx` (con un `+` al final indicando que contiene ACLs):

```
$ touch <directorio>/archivo
$ getfacl <directorio>/archivo 
# file: <directorio>/archivo
# owner: usuario
# group: grupo
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::rw-

$ mkdir <directorio>/subdirectorio
$ getfacl <directorio>/subdirectorio 
# file: <directorio>/subdirectorio
# owner: usuario
# group: grupo
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::rwx

$ ls -ltr <directorio>
total 4
-rw-rw-rw-  1 usuario grupo      0 ago 19 11:59 archivo
drwxrwxrwx+ 2 usuario grupo   4096 ago 19 12:00 subdirectorio
```

Comment: He probado umask(0) pero desafortunadamente me muestra el mismo resultado. He visto que has añadido una nota adicional donde me indicas que el directorio padre no tiene permisos de ejecución. La verdad no lo entiendo he ejecutado chmod -R 777 en el directorio padre(al principio del post tienes los permisos) y no los hereda entonces?

Comment: He añadido los permisos de ejecución en el directorio padre pero el resultado es el mismo. En mi código php también he añadido umask(0) tal y como se indica en la documentación oficial de PHP. El resultado es el mismo únicamente me hereda rw del propietario.

Comment: Por pasos: 1.- El permiso `x` debería tenerlo únicamente los scripts que tengan que ser ejecutados desde el sistema operativo, por eso por mucho que cambies `umask` el permiso otorgado a un archivo creado será `rw-` (sin el `x`). Si quieres agregarlo debes hacerlo explícitamente con `chmod()`. 2.- Es al directorio padre de `Z_LISTADO`, no al directorio padre de los archivos. 3.- Como te pongo en mi respuesta, **los permisos no pueden heredarse** sin hacer uso de ACLs. 4.- Con ACLs sería `setfacl -d -m u::rwx,g::rwx,o::rwx <directorio>`.

Comment: He agregado una amplia explicación de las ACLs y cómo usarlas en tu caso. Necesitarás acceso SSH al servidor o bien que puedas ejecutar instrucciones del sistema operativo desde PHP (usando `system()`, por ejemplo). Si borras el directorio y lo creas de nuevo tendrás que repetir el proceso nuevamente. Si haces un backup de los archivos debes hacer uso del parámetro adecuado de tu cliente de backup para que tenga en cuenta las ACLs (por defecto la mayoría de herramientas sólo tienen en cuenta los permisos UNIX normales).